# My terminal is invisible

Tags: 11.04, command-line

I have just moved to Natty from Maverick and suddenly my terminal is invisible.

I can type commands and they get executed, but I don't see a thing - only cursor changes when the terminal area is active. What might be wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: A screenshot would be useful here.

Comment: How my screenshot would be useful, if you can't see any thing there :-P? Anyway, I managed to bring it back by turning all compiz effects, including opengl support. Any idea how I may have both my terminal and compiz running?

Comment: Same problem here, on an Ubuntu Natty 64 bit upgrade. Application is there (I can choose it with ctrl+alt+tab, but it isn't visible.

Comment: @Gruszczy: at least we can see how you experience it.

Comment: @Suhrawardi Yep, I have 64bit too.

Comment: Do you by chance have Compiz installed?

Comment: Yes I do. When I turned it off, the terminal became visible. But other things till aren't displayed, like top bars of windows.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install **CompizConfig SettingsManager**

   `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
2. Launch it by searching from the dash in **Unity**, or **Preferences > CompizConfig Settings Manager** in **Ubuntu Classic**.
3. Ensure that the **Opacify**, and
   **Opacity, Brightness, and Saturation**
   plugins are both disabled.
   [image]

Comment: I have done it all before, because I had compizconfig settingsmanager. Now I just reverted to maverick.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. If for whatever reason you give Natty another shot in the future, come'on back.

Comment: I probably will, but I will wait until it works better. Or maybe I'll just wait for Ocelot.