# Terminal shows menu in panel but window is missing

Tags: 11.04, gnome-terminal

I upgraded from 10.10. Then everything worked well except very important one -- my terminal.

I try to open my terminal, but no any window popup. I press `alt+tab` and the windows switcher appears in which there is the terminal. I switch to it, however, nothing happens.

I can see the word `terminal` in my top bar. When I move cursor on it I see the `file` `edit` `view` and so on. But they are useless unless I can find my terminal window.

I have no problem with chrome, firefox, eclipse, ubuntu software center, pidgin and many more applications. But without terminal, I'm using a disabled linux.

Comment: Have you got multiple screens?

Comment: This could be a duplicate of [My terminal is invisible](http://askubuntu.com/q/37714/667) and both may be a bug. You can report this as a bug by pressing alt+F2 and entering `ubuntu-bug gnome-terminal`.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

I switch to ROXterm to replace gnome-terminal.
It works well. But I'm still wondering if I can use gnome-terminal in Natty.

Answer (score 1):

Try logging into ubuntu through guest account(instead of your normal user account). If in guest account it appears normally then there is some configuration setting which you have to change. If even in guest account it appears in the same way then there might be a bug.

Answer (score -2):

Just click the Ubuntu logo in the top left corner, then type in "terminal" in the search bar. It comes up under apps. Should be good to go after that.

Comment: I know what terminal is and how to launch it. But I can't see it when it is running.